# Swagger UI route giving 404 Not found error - NestJs Swagger Module

Tags: node.js, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

On my localhost, swagger-ui document API route is working fine - http:://localhost:3000/api.

But, when I deployed the nestjs build on server (AWS with Apache server), the same route is not working.

In nestjs "main.ts" file, following code is written to initialize swagger.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';


    async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      app.enableCors();
    
      const config = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('Digital Health')
        .setDescription('Digital Health API')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .build();
      const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
      SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
    
      await app.listen(4000);
    }
    bootstrap();
```

I'm getting this error, when I hit the backend API url to access swagger documentation.

[image]

Comment: I've got the same issue but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way! and also clear the server cache :

```
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
 SwaggerModule.setup("api", app, document, {
 swaggerOptions: { defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1 },
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Increase the memory of your lambda function and it should work

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be more helpful if you show how to do it in a nice formatted code.